# Converting dtype object to hourly datetimes in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df` in Python with `Dtype` of  `df['timestamp']` as `object`

The actual data in the `timestamp` column consists of hourly date times:

```
01012011 0:00 
01012011 1:00  
01012011 2:00  
... 
01012011 22:00  
01012011 23:00  
01012011 24:00  
...
```

etc.,

I want to convert the `Dtype` to `datetime64` and tried `df_1['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['timestamp'])` but received the following error  `ParserError: month must be in 1..12: 01012011 0:00`. I believe there is a simple solution but haven't managed to figure it out yet.

Comment: You'll need to set the format for pd.to_datetime explicitly: `format='%d%m%Y %H:%S'` (make sure the order of %d and %m is correct; adjust if needed).

Comment: Thank you, is it strange that ```pd.to_datetime('01012011 00:00',format='%d%m%Y %H:%M')``` works, whereas  ```pd.to_datetime('06162013 19:00',format='%d%m%Y %H:%M')``` prompts ```ValueError: time data '06162013 19:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M' (match)```. I think I am not understanding something.

Comment: as I noted in parentheses: make sure the order of day and month is correct. `'06162013 19:00'` is month first, so format is `'%m%d%Y %H:%S'`.

Comment: Wow, sorry about that. Thank you

Comment: no worries, glad it helped. https://strftime.org/ is a lucid resource to get the formatting directives

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As suggested my MrFuppes, you can try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
functools import partial
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':['01012011 0:00 ']},index=['tst'])
to_datetime_fmt = partial(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(to_datetime_fmt)
```

Comment: The OP has a pandas DataFrame; you'll want to use pandas methods with that (see my comment on the question).

Comment: Thank you @roshshetty, I tried both ```%H:%M``` and ```%k:%M``` for the format, and both returned ```NaT``` in the timestamp column. I believe ```%k:%M``` is the correct format since it is 24 hour without leading zeros, but I don't see why that isn't working.